# docker: Error response from daemon: could not select device driver "" with capabilities: [[gpu]]

Tags: drivers, 20.04, nvidia, docker, gpu

Despite having 4 GPUs each with ~20GB vRAM, docker is not able to run with the following command. How can I solve this?

```
[20:08:28] jalal@echo:~/research/code$ docker run --shm-size 2GB -it --gpus all docurdt/heal
docker: Error response from daemon: could not select device driver "" with capabilities: [[gpu]].
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled 


[20:08:20] jalal@echo:~/research/code$ nvidia-smi
Fri Apr  1 20:08:28 2022       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 510.47.03    Driver Version: 510.47.03    CUDA Version: 11.6     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 31%   41C    P8    23W / 350W |    301MiB / 24576MiB |      1%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:21:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 30%   39C    P8    18W / 350W |     14MiB / 24576MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:4A:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 30%   32C    P8    23W / 350W |     14MiB / 24576MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   3  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:4B:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 30%   40C    P8    18W / 350W |     14MiB / 24576MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

I also have:

```
$ uname -a
Linux echo 5.4.0-99-generic #112-Ubuntu SMP Thu Feb 3 13:50:55 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch:security-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

$ docker -v
Docker version 20.10.7, build 20.10.7-0ubuntu5~20.04.2
```

Also,

```
$ df -h | grep /dev/shm
tmpfs                                126G  199M  126G   1% /dev/shm
```

and

[image]

and

```
$  cat /boot/config-$(uname -r) | grep -i seccomp
CONFIG_SECCOMP=y
CONFIG_HAVE_ARCH_SECCOMP_FILTER=y
CONFIG_SECCOMP_FILTER=y
```

and

```
[20:33:17] (dpcc) jalal@echo:~$ lspci -vv | grep -i nvidia
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 2204 (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1aef (rev a1)
21:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 2204 (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
21:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1aef (rev a1)
4a:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 2204 (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
4a:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1aef (rev a1)
4b:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 2204 (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
4b:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1aef (rev a1)
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

1. `$ distribution=$(. /etc/os-release;echo $ID$VERSION_ID)       && curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/gpgkey | sudo apt-key add -       && curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/$distribution/libnvidia-container.list | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-container-toolkit.list`
2. `$ sudo apt-get update`
3. `$ sudo apt-get install -y nvidia-docker2`
4. `$ sudo systemctl restart docker`
5. `$ docker run --shm-size 2GB -it --gpus all docurdt/heal (base) root@9f66ed7b7c1b:/Workspace#`

Thanks a lot `grym` for [link](https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/cloud-native/container-toolkit/install-guide.html).

Comment: All the steps mentioned above worked for me except the **step-1**. Please refer to this for more details about step 1: https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/. 
Also, you might need to do `sudo apt-get install -y nvidia-container-toolkit` for **step-3**.

Answer (score 0):

the following three commands solved my problem

```
sudo apt install -y nvidia-docker2 
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

here is the source
https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/could-not-select-device-driver-with-capabilities-gpu/80200